# I get an AttributeError error when trying to access self.img variable

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import cv2
import random
import os

class Pyditor:
    def __init__(self, img):
        self.filename = img
        self.img = Image.open(img)
        self.copiedArea = None
    
    def paste(self, sample, dest):
        x, y = dest
        try:
            self.img.paste(sample, dest)
        except:
            print("file not found")

    def copy(self, area):
        _area = self.img.crop(area)
        self.copiedArea = _area

    def CopiedArea(self):
        return self.copiedArea
    
    def rotate(self, dg):
        img = self.img.rotate(dg)
        self.img = img

    def save(self):
        newFilename = f"{random.randint(100, 10000)}{random.randint(100, 10000)}{random.randint(100, 10000)}{random.randint(100, 10000)}.png"
        self.img.save(newFilename)
        return newFilename
```

Comment: Hi, can you add the error message to the question pls?

Comment: Just tried to reproduce an error by reading, rotating and saving a file with your code and it works without any issue. In addition to the error and the printed stack trace please provide more information of how you call your class when you get the error!

Comment: please remove opencv tag (not used)

Comment: cv tag is used in this class, but I showed only used functions